# Old Mans Cooking Quest - Too late to complete?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I think I have got too far in the main quest to complete the old Mans Cooking Quest and get the warm doublet.   I have made the meal, but when I go to the campsite in the woods the old man is not there.  If I light the fire and then wait until night he does not appear.   By this point I have already completed the four shrines.

I take it then I have gone too far in the main quest (the old man is now supposed to be waiting at the place between the four shrines so I assume he won't be anywhere else)

And if so,  is there another way to get warm clothes in order to go into cold places?  Do I even need to now that I have done that shrine in the mountains? (I got there using a torch)

Comment: Regarding your second part of the question: There are other armor pieces that grant cold resistance, you will probably encounter them naturally during your playthrough. Just search for shops near a very cold region.

Comment: Regarding the second question in the second part: It seems to me like back then, you had been thinking you're almost done with the game, while in fact you had just almost completed the (relatively tiny) tutorial section (although it's possible to end the game quickly afterwards).

Comment: @EgorHans I wasn't thinkng I was almost done.  I knew I was very much near the beginning. 'Too far' in this case is not synonymous with 'Too near the end',  just 'Too far past a point where it's possible to complete that particular quest'.    As it happens, years later I got very bored of the game.  I try to pick it up every now and then but just end up running around collecting stuff, exploring, jumping off hills, and then quiting the game again :(

Comment: I just had that impression primarily from this passage: "Do I even need to now that I have done that shrine in the mountains?", which seems to imply that you assumed there won't be any more cold areas. I probably jumped to conclusions from that, because it would be very well possible (and, in fact, technically is the case) that all future cold areas are optional, which I didn't consider.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go ahead and meet with the old man like he asked, then after the meeting return to his cabin/house. There should be a chest there with the warm doublet, and a note.

Comment: What does the note say?